# how to detect the tab selection in android to validate the edit texts?

Tags: android

I have four tabs A,B,C,D which having some edit texts in each of them. set current tab(0) makes me tab A visible initially. I want to validate whether the edit texts are null or not in tab A. When i click on tab B, if the edit texts are not null then only i want to go for tab B. Otherwise i want to stay on tab A with some alerts like the values needed to be filled. how can i do it? kindly help..

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, A.class);
tab = tabHost.newTabSpec("A");
tab.setIndicator("A");
tab.setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(tab);
```

Comment: Use an if statement that detects when you change the tab and if the fields are null.

Comment: In activity of TAB1 you can use sharedPrefence and when you click on TAB2 check that editTExt value is null or not by use of SharedPrefence, then you can able to track it or you can use putextra